# How to reinitialize jQuery plugins with ES6 JS after ajax page load

Tags: javascript, ajax, webpack, ecmascript-6

I recently built a website that uses a [router system](https://github.com/UseAllFive/slater-base) to load each page via ajax. The site is compiled using webpack and is structured as ES6 JavaScript modules. I am using some third-party jQuery plugins that only work if you refresh the page.

My question is how do I reinitialize or load third-party jQuery plugins and/or scripts using ES6 JS after an ajax page load?

For example, I am using the [Elevate Zoom](https://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/) plugin to add an image zoom on images. When I navigate to another page on the site that uses this, the zoom breaks and only works again when re-loading the page.

```
$("#img_01").elevateZoom();
```

Something like the below?

```js
import { component } from 'picoapp';
// import elevate zoom  
// import jQuery 


export default component(() => {

  // reinitialize plugin here?
  //$("#img_01").elevateZoom();

})
```

Comment: Well, did you try that? Did it work? If not, did it throw an error?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, so it seems to have worked. Dah. I guess I didn't think it would using jQuery inside ES6 so thanks for the gentle nudging!

I should've said I'm very new to ES6 and the world of Webpack.

```js
import { component } from 'picoapp';
import $ from "jquery";
import zoom from '../lib/elevatezoom.js'


export default component(() => {

    $(".zoom").elevateZoom({
      zoomType: "inner",
      cursor: "zoom-in"
    }); 

})
```

Comment: Well it did work momentarily but then I changed some scss, the project was compiled and now I'm getting the below error message despite the JS above being the same.


picoapp.es.js:1 TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default(...)(...).elevateZoom is not a function